# How to implement a Https web server using SslStream and a self signed certificate?

Tags: c#, ssl, x509certificate, sslstream, makecert

The problem was that SslStream always read 0 bytes because the chrome web browser cannot validate the server's certificate.

Refer to the msdn sample code:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx

I created the server side certificate with makecert.exe:

```
makecert    
    -pe                                     Exportable private key
    -n "CN=Test"                            Subject name
    -ss my                                  Certificate store name
    -sr LocalMachine                        Certificate store location
    -a sha1                                 Signature algorithm
    -sky signature                          Subject key type is for signature purposes
    -r                                      Make a self-signed cert
    "output.cer"                            Output filename
```

2. I've successfully installed the generated cert file in Local Computer -> Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

3. Launch the server and access https://localhost from the web browser

When calling the Read method from SslStream (which created based on a network stream), it always return 0 bytes.

**Is there any steps missing so as to let the browser talk with the SslStream successfully?**

Comment: Show relevant code. If you're trying to implement a HTTP server with TLS support you may want to narrow the issue down a bit to a very specific question, otherwise this is way too broad.

Comment: Change CN from test to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Change CN from test to localhost, then the chrome web browser was able to talk to the sslstream.